# The ViewData item that has the key 'officeId' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

> Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Cadastrar()
    {

        ViewBag.officelist = new SelectList(new OfficeREP().ListarTodos(),
           "id",
           "estado"
       );

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Cadastrar(OpportunityMOD opportunidade)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var opportunity01 = new OpportunityREP();
            opportunity01.Salvar(opportunidade);
            TempData["mensagem"] = "Cadastro realizado com Sucesso!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(opportunidade);

    }
```

> Model

```
    [DisplayName("Escritório")]
    public string officeId { get; set; }
```

> View

```
                <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.officeId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.officeId,(SelectList)ViewBag.officeList, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.officeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: O engraçado que estava funcionando normal, agora parou e acusa este erro... não entendo o que aconteceu. Ele lista normal na hora de gravar ele dá este erro.

Comment: Tira essa linha  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.officeId,(SelectList)ViewBag.officeList, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Tirei, mais ai não lista, ok.

Comment: Então, você está tentando gerar uma LISTA de uma STRING, esse é o problema

Comment: Ok, mais como eu vou listar os objetos e gravar como string no banco de dados. Porque antes ele listava e grava, sabe me dizer ?

Comment: Liste uma lista e não uma string

Comment: Ainda sem sucesso.

Comment: Como você listou?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35247/discussion-between-paulohdsousa-and-rodrigo-borghi).

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

O problema é que você está tentando listar uma string.

Nesta linha.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.officeId,(SelectList)ViewBag.officeList, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Depois, faça assim

Model

```
[DisplayName("Escritório")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> officeId { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.officelist = new SelectList(new OfficeREP().ListarTodos(), 
"id", 
"estado" 
);
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.officeId,(SelectList)ViewBag.officeList, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```